# How to get lines that contain only one of the patterns?

Tags: python, bash, dataframe, filtering

I would like to filter out a dataframe in bash or python so that I can get the rows that contain only one of the patterns given and nothing else.

Example:

Dataframe:

```
OG1   Abc1  Def1  Klm3  
OG2   Def1  Ghj1  Abc3
OG3   Ghj2  Abc1  Abc2
OG4   Nop5  Ghj7
```

Searched patterns: `Abc[0-9]*`, `Ghj[0-9]*`, `Nop[0-9]*`

Desired output:

```
OG3  Ghj2  Abc1  Abc2
OG4  Nop5  Ghj7
```

Comment: OG3 doesn't match any of the patterns? Is the first column excluded from matching?

Comment: If your original input is plain text, then would [`^\w+(?:\s+(?:Abc|Ghj|Nop)\d*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/R5yLEW/1) do it? with the `m` and `g` flags set?

Comment: The first line contains `Abc1` that matches `Abc[0-9]*`. Why is it not in your desired output? Because you want to select only lines where all fields match one of your regular expressions? Probably not because the first field never matches. Same for the second line that contains `Ghj1` (matching `Ghj[0-9]*`) and `Abc3` (matching `Abc[0-9]*`). Please check your examples, edit your question and fix what needs to be.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading dataframes, the first column is just rownames. OG1 contains Abc1 that matches one of the patterns but it also contains other patterns that are not desired. That is why it is not in desired output. Exactly, I would like select lines where all fields match one of my regular expressions.

Comment: Better update your question: nobody will read the comments to know what you are really asking and the question and the comment are contradictory ("I would like select lines where all fields match one of my regular expressions" against "get the rows that contain only one of the patterns"). So you want only one pattern on some field? Or one pattern in all fields? Or any pattern in some field? Or any patterns in all fields?

Comment: Lines with IDs `OPG3` and `OG4` have fields that does not "match one of my regular expressions", it matches two of them.

Comment: `grep -E 'X|Y|Z' filename` returns all lines which match one of the extended regular expressions X or Y or Z.

Comment: Why is `OG4  Nop5  Ghj7` in the expected output when it matches 2 of the regexps, `Ghj[0-9]*` and `Nop[0-9]*`, and you say you want to output `the rows that contain only one of the patterns given and nothing else`?

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk, one way to "get the rows that contain only one of the patterns given and nothing else" as stated in the question would be:

```
$ awk '{c=0} /Abc[0-9]*/{c++} /Ghj[0-9]*/{c++} /Nop[0-9]*/{c++} c==1' file
OG1   Abc1  Def1  Klm3
```

You could provide regexps on the command line using this if you prefer:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { while (ARGC > 2) rs[ARGV[ARGC--]] }
    { c=0; for (r in rs) if ($0 ~ r) c++ }
    c == 1
' file 'Abc[0-9]*' 'Ghj[0-9]*' 'Nop[0-9]*'
OG1   Abc1  Def1  Klm3
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm doing something wrong, you're search pattern, also tried on regex101, does not return any line.

Because if we're searching for one of the followings: Abc[0-9]*, Ghj[0-9]*, Nop[0-9]*

OG1 should also appear

In any case, the python code, that will fulfill what you're looking for, would be the following:

```py
import re

data = open("NAME_OF_YOUR_DATAFRAME_FILE.txt")
pattern = "YOUR_RE_PATTERN"

for line in data:
    if re.match(pattern, line):
        print(line)
```

Of course, replacing it with the right pattern

Maybe some pattern like this one? /Ghj[0-9]{1,} Abc[0-9]{1,}/

Comment: OG1 contains Abc1 that matches one of the patterns but it also contains other patterns that are not desired. I would like select lines where all fields match one of my regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only the lines where all fields except the first match one of your regular expressions, `awk` is a good choice:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if($i!~/^(Abc|Ghj|Nop)[0-9]*$/) next }1' file
OG3   Ghj2  Abc1  Abc2
OG4   Nop5  Ghj7
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to get the job done. Could you please tell me also how I can add other regular expressions in your code? For example lets say Exp_a1_123.

Comment: Replace `/^(Abc|Ghj|Nop)[0-9]*$/` with `/^((Abc|Ghj|Nop)[0-9]*|Exp_a1_123)$/`. But if you want to learn regular expressions a tutorial would be much better than SO comments.

Answer (score 0):

*(edited)*
Using this input file -

```
$: cat file
OG1     Abc1    Def1    Klm3
OG2     Def1    Ghj1    Abc3
OG3     Ghj2    Abc1    Abc2
OG4     Nop5    Ghj7    Exp_a1_123
OG5     fooAbc1bar
```

You *could* use `grep`.

```
$: grep -E '^[^[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+(Exp_a1_123|(Abc|Ghj|Nop)[0-9]*))+$' file
OG3     Ghj2    Abc1    Abc2
OG4     Nop5    Ghj7    Exp_a1_123
```

Responding to cango's question on [Reynaud's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77793031/8656552), I put the individual patterns in a file and stacked them -

```
$: cat pats
Abc[0-9]*
Ghj[0-9]*
Nop[0-9]*
Exp_a1_123

$: awk '
  # initialize the search pattern to allow for rownames
  NR==1          { p="^[^[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+("$0; next; }
  # load each pattern from the 1st file as alternate matches
  NR==FNR        { p=p"|"$0;                           next; }
  # finalize by anchoring to EOL so pattern check ALL cols
  NR>1 && FNR==1 { p=p"))+$"                                 }
  # then print each record that matches from 2nd file
  NR>FNR && $0 ~ p
  END{ print "Used pattern: "p }
' pats file
OG3     Ghj2    Abc1    Abc2
OG4     Nop5    Ghj7    Exp_a1_123
Used pattern: ^[^[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+(Abc[0-9]*|Ghj[0-9]*|Nop[0-9]*|Exp_a1_123))+$
```

On one line:

```
$: awk 'NR==1{p="^[^[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+("$0;next} NR==FNR{p=p"|"$0;next} NR>1&&FNR==1{p=p"))+$"} NR>FNR && $0 ~ p' pats file
OG3     Ghj2    Abc1    Abc2
OG4     Nop5    Ghj7    Exp_a1_123
```

Please note Reynaud's [caveats](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) on using patterns this way, such as the possible need for double-escaping or disallowed escape characters, and of course any possibility of misapplied metacharacters in your data.

Always test.

Comment: This will not work as expected if one of the lines is, for instance, `OG5   fooAbc1bar`. And strings used as regular expressions have a number of drawbacks. To fully understand you can read, for instance, [this part of the GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps). You'll see that creating a correct `pats` file, in the general case, is not that easy.

Comment: True. Elaborating the patterns in the file could help, but there are numerous concerns to address. Was just offering a direction.

Answer (score 0):

either directly add them up ...

```
echo '
OG1   Abc1  Def1  Klm3  
OG2   Def1  Ghj1  Abc3
OG3   Ghj2  Abc1  Abc2
OG4   Nop5  Ghj7' |
```

---

```
gawk '/ Abc[0-9]+( |$)/ + / Ghj[0-9]+( |$)/ + / Nop[0-9]+( |$)/ == 1'

OG1   Abc1  Def1  Klm3
```

> ...or let `FS` do all the heavy lifting ...

```
mawk NF==2 FS='(^|[ \t])(Abc|Ghj|Nop)[0-9]+([ \t]|$)'     

OG1   Abc1  Def1  Klm3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -P 'Abc[0-9]*|Ghj[0-9]*|Nop[0-9]*' file
```